# Pattern matching in python W/O regex

Tags: python, nlp, pattern-matching, nltk

I have the challenge of find & replace patterns in order to normalize a paragraph. It's easier to understand with an example: I have a lot of words like:

- nm5638238.tmp, nm23345.tmp, nm56382334.tmp, etc
- myfile0x233454, myfile0x233124, myfile0x23AW54, etc

and so on. The thing is that I don't like the regex approach in the sense that is so custom (I mean, I need one regex for each case). I need an "unattended" approach, like find that one pattern is for example myfileSOMETHING, another is nmSOMETHING.tmp, etc etc. Is there any NLP technique that you can suggest to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, You have to know the pattern in order to find & replace it, right? Effectively, regex is not custom but a regular language. You could build your own automaton, but I mean, you would end up with a regex-like module anyways. You do not need one expression for each of hundreds(?) of your strange filenames, but one for nm[0-9]*.tmp and one for myfile0x[0-9]* in order to match your expressions. Maybe have a look at regex syntax again: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax.
You could go one step higher on the chomsky hierarchy, but with no benefit I assume.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you wouldn't need that many regex's to solve this. I mean, if those are your two patterns, you could even just go:
(if 'para' is your paragraph string)

```
import re
new_para = re.sub(r'myfile\S+|nm\S+', 'REPLACEMENT STRING', para)
```

Does that work for you?